# How to fix cannot resolve method 'findViewById'

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, streaming

I am building a radio streaming app using fragments and I am having problems in the line:

```
b_play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_play);
```

I have tried "Create method for 'findViewById' in 'RadioFragment'

```
b_play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_play);
b_play.setEnabled(false);
b_play.setText("LOADING");
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
new PlayerTask().execute(stream);
```

The app does not run because of the error, I would like to fix that.

Comment: In your XML file, you define <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_play"

Comment: Govind Parashar I already had that line on my XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Add your view to this line

```
b_play = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b_play);
```

Comment: MartijndeM I added view to the line and there is a new error: "error: cannot find symbol variable view". It also states that: "uses or overrides a deprecated API."

Comment: MartijndeM I have reply to your query on answer 3.